# how to fix the unicode problem in python (UnicodeEncodeError)

Tags: python, utf-8, encode

I have `Persian sentence` and I read that from terminal like this

```
tdf = sys.argv[1]  # sentence => سلام خوبی؟
print(make_a_call(tdf))
```

when I do this Its working fine

```
sentence = 'سلام خوبی؟'
print(make_a_call(sentence))
```

the `Error` is this

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 13: character maps to

I added `.encode("utf-8")` to my code but it's not solve the problem

```
tdf = sys.argv[1].encode("utf-8")
print(make_a_call(tdf))
```

Comment: What encoding is your system using?

Comment: The problem is the output console. Save to a file, or configure your console/terminal to accept unicode data. Note: you use a `make_a_call`, but you didn't define in the question: if it is uneded, just remove it. But do a test with the exact code you send here.